# ASP.NET Cannot find column

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datacontext

I met the error of `Cannot find column CustomerItemNoAppend.` when I clicked on my search button.

Condition: If user is not internal, hide 2 columns. My current query did not involve the column `CustomerItemNoAppend` and `ManufacturerItemNoAppend`.

Suggested by @tetsuya-yamamoto, I would not meet the error of `Cannot find column` when `getColumnSafe` is used.

```
public IQueryable GetAllInventorySummary()
{
var query = from summary in dataContext.Q_TBL_INVENTORY_SUMMARIES

            group summary by new
            {
                poaItemNo = summary.POAItemNo,
                customerItemNo = summary.CustomerItemNo,
                manufacturerItemNo = summary.ManufacturerItemNo,
                itemDescription = summary.ItemDescription,
                uom = summary.UOM,

            } into grp
            select new
            {
                POAItemNo = grp.Key.poaItemNo,
                CustomerItemNo = grp.Key.customerItemNo,
                ManufacturerItemNo = grp.Key.manufacturerItemNo,
                ItemDescription = grp.Key.itemDescription,
                OnHandQty = grp.Sum(s => s.OnHandQty),
                UOM = grp.Key.uom,
                InventoryLocationNo = "All",
            };
return query;
}
```

Main method:

```
    if (profile.UserInternal != 'Y')
    {  
        RadGrid1.DataSource = inventory.GetAllInventorySummary(profile.CompanyID);
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("CustomerItemNoAppend").Visible = false;
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("ManufacturerItemNoAppend").Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        RadGrid1.DataSource = inventory.GetAllInventorySummary();
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("CustomerItemNo").Visible = false;
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("ManufacturerItemNo").Visible = false;  
    }
}
else
{
    if (profile.UserInternal != 'Y')
    {
        RadGrid1.DataSource = inventory.GetInventorySummaryByLocation(InventoryLocation.SelectedValue);
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("CustomerItemNoAppend").Visible = false;
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("ManufacturerItemNoAppend").Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        RadGrid1.DataSource = inventory.GetInventorySummaryByLocation(InventoryLocation.SelectedValue);
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("CustomerItemNo").Visible = false;
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("ManufacturerItemNo").Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Search Button:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InventoryProvider inventory = new InventoryProvider();
    GetInventorySummary();
    DataProvider.CloseConnectionDB();
    RadGrid1.DataBind();
}
```

Telerik Radgrid columns:

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Customer Item No." UniqueName="CustomerItemNo"
    HeaderStyle-Width="150px" SortExpression="CustomerItemNo" DataField="CustomerItemNo"
    DataType="System.String" />
<telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Manufacturer Item No." UniqueName="ManufacturerItemNo"
    SortExpression="ManufacturerItemNo" DataField="ManufacturerItemNo" DataType="System.String" />


            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Customer Item No. Appended" UniqueName="CustomerItemNoAppend"
    HeaderStyle-Width="150px" SortExpression="CustomerItemNoAppend" DataField="CustomerItemNoAppend"
    DataType="System.String" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Manufacturer Item No. Appended" UniqueName="ManufacturerItemNoAppend"
    HeaderStyle-Width="150px" SortExpression="ManufacturerItemNoAppend" DataField="ManufacturerItemNoAppend"
    DataType="System.String" />
```

Comment: My apologies. Typo. I will correct my post.

Comment: Could you alter your query to return `CustomerItemNoAppend` etc (e.g. as a blank string)? For example `CustomerItemNo = grp.Key.customerItemNo, CustomerItemNoAppend = "",`.

Comment: I will try now!

Comment: @mjwills after altering, I am able to load the page, just that the 2 columns are empty.